# What does it mean, if no response for ping (not even timeout)?

Tags: networking, connection, ping, timeout

I'm trying to ping a VM from KVM Host over the bridge (maybe this informations is redundant).
And there is no response to the ping, not even `"host unreachable"` or `"timeout"`
What does it mean?

## Update:

- Host: Debian 7.1 + Proxmox (KVM)
- Guest: Debian 7.1

Comment: What OS, host and guest?

Comment: It probably means the bridge interface driver is broken. What virtualization software? I assume the host can ping elsewhere without trouble?

Comment: virtualization sw: proxmox as manager, and KVM (QEMU emulator version 1.4.2, Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard) for concrete VMs.
yes, I can ping elsewhere without trouble